# Editing a memoir

Tags: editing, authorship, memoir

A relative (who is no longer living) wrote a number of autobiographical pieces which I would like to publish in a book.  They're very good but they need a fair amount of editing.  I would like to include some chapters written by myself, that would supplement the relative's memories.  How to I put my name on the cover and title page?  If I were only writing one chapter, I could call that an epilogue and say:

***Title***

*by Relative*

*edited and with an epilogue by Aparente*

But this won't work if I contribute three or four chapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it depends on the nature of the project and  your contributions.

Personally I wouldn't list yourself as an editor; just explain it in the preface.

Try: (Additional) Background and commentary by aparente001.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading a book called [*A Monster Calls*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Monster_Calls), which had the same thing going on. The original idea was from Siobhan Dowd, but she died, and the book was completed by Patrick Ness. I would do something similar:

> Originally written by X. Completed by Y.

I would have an afterword detailing the writing of the novel, and the parts you contributed to as well as edited to make the 'completion' more clear.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Good idea, but it isn't accurate in my particular case.  However, this will come in handy for others.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

*Title*

by Relative

with Aparente

(I have also seen "as told to," which to me means the person in question sat for multiple interviews and the writer collated and wrote everything down in first person even though it wasn't the writer's story.)

Comment: Good idea, for a relative who didn't write things down and craft the heck out of it (like mine did).  (My editing mainly consists of chopping up veery long sentences.)